# Does centos8 not support the system-config-users package?

Tags: linux, centos, gui

Does centos8 not support the system-config-users package? I've also modified the file path and checked the internet connection, but I still can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the system-config-* tools were removed in RHEL/CentOS 8. system-config-user isn't available in EPEL either. If you are on server, you should use either the command line tools or [Cockpit](https://cockpit-project.org/) and if you are on desktop then the GNOME Control Center (Settings) provides some user management options.